# Xcode not showing OCMock verification errors in the source code

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, ocmock

When unit testing in Xcode, if I use `OCUnit` `STAssertX` methods, `OCHamcrest` assertions or `OCMockito`, when any of those raise an error I can see that Xcode marks that line in red in the editor. However, with `OCMock` Xcode does not show the line in red, so I have to check the issues tab to see which test method is failing. Do you know any way to solve this? I would really like to see the verify line in red when a verification is failing.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't show the red line for `[myMock verify]`? Or for something else? If verify, try `STAssertNoThrows([myMock verify], @"Unexpected!")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works perfectly! I didn't think in that solution. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCMock's `verify` method works by throwing an exception, which is something you can take advantage of.

```
STAssertNoThrows([myMock verify], @"Unexpected!");
```

The `STAssertNoThrows` will be highlighted by Xcode if the `verify` fails.

**EDIT**

A macro can make this look nicer:

```
#define STVerify(MOCK) STAssertNoThrow([MOCK verify], @"Mock failed to verify")
STVerify(myMock);
```